# Run code when page has loaded into the div

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've got a system, on which I need to share a true/false-value across several domains, using a 3rd party cookie.

Running the remote cookiefile directly (iframe), works - however, when invoked from Ajax (with and without jQuery), the cookie is never set. Another thing; it has to be done in plain Javascript without jQuery, because I need to keep the file size to a minimum.

I did some experimenting and this code did the trick:

```
document.write("<div id='dummy'>test</div>");
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="http://stats.***.com/setcookie.php"></object>';
```

The remote file echoes a "isvalid=true" or "isvalid=false" into the div, but a piece is missing:

I need to process the answer. At the moment, the result is just displayed in the DIV, so I need to find out, when the DIV named "dummy" changes value and react to it.

The listeners below are not a very elegant solution, I know... and doesn't work, but they show the intentions.

```
document.getElementById("dummy").onchange = function(e) {
    alert("do process");
}
// another test
document.getElementById("dummy").onload = function(e) {
    alert("do process");
}
```

Any idea to how to handle the result for further processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing... I did not find a solution without using external libraries, so I'm using minified.js. The file size is a bit more acceptable and I plan to remove some unneccesary methods in order to reduce the size even more.

Low file size is essential, since millions of requests per week will be made.